# pythonEnv specific PATH not respected when debugging flask with my launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python Environment where executables are provided necessary for my flask app. If i debug with this launch.json:

```
    {
    "name": "Python: Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "module": "flask",
    "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "server.py"
    },
    "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--no-reload"
    ],
    "jinja": true
},
```

I get issues when I'm calling executables in my environment because the PATH is not set correctly. I'm expecting a PATH similar to this:

```
    "PATH": "/home/MyUsername/src/specter-desktop/.env/bin:/home/MyUsername/.local/bin:/home/MyuSername/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/kim/.dotnet/tools"
```

Indeed if i add the path above in the "env"-section, it works as expected. Is this a bug? A missing feature? Should i file an issue?
Adding it in that way to the launch.json is cumbersome as it's not portable to my fellow coders.

Comment: What is the `PATH` you are getting and thus what are the key differences?